# Apache CXF org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '404: Not Found' when communicating to end point URL

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ant, cxf

I Am trying to migrate form axis to cxf because of its jax-rs support, but its not as easy as I thought it would be.
I have created a sample webservice application and deployed it to tomcat using ANT. When I check $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/OrderProcessingSystem/WEB-INF, everything seems ok.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  711 Oct 16 11:33 beans.xml
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Oct 16 11:34 classes
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Oct 16 12:53 lib
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  787 Oct 16 12:36 web.xml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    6 Oct 16 11:34 wsdl
```

My beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" /> 
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" /> 

    <jaxws:endpoint 
      id="orderProcess" 
      implementor="com.orderProcess.service.OrderProcessImpl" 
      address="/OrderProcess" />

</beans>
```

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC 
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My client code:

```
import com.orderProcess.service.Order;
import com.orderProcess.service.OrderProcess;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public final class Client {  
    public Client() {
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // START SNIPPET: client
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ClientBeans.xml");
        OrderProcess client = (OrderProcess) context.getBean("orderClient");
    // Populate the Order bean
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setCustomerID("C001");
        order.setItemID("I001");
        order.setQty(100);
        order.setPrice(200.00);
        String orderID = client.processOrder(order);
        String message = (orderID == null) ? "Order not approved" : "Order approved;order ID is " + orderID;
        System.out.println(message);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

CLient beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
                           http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <jaxws:client 
        id="orderClient" 
        serviceClass="com.orderProcess.service.OrderProcess" 
        address="http://127.0.0.1:8080/OrderProcess" />
</beans>
```

My ant build (same as the default for cxf ant build but with some small modifications):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
  or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file
  distributed with this work for additional information
  regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file
  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
  specific language governing permissions and limitations
  under the License.
-->
<project name="Hello world demo" default="compile" basedir=".">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="build.dir" location="${basedir}/build"/>
    <property name="build.classes.dir" location="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="src.dir" location="${basedir}/src"/>
    <property name="build.src.dir" location="${build.dir}/src"/>
    <property name="build.var.dir" location="${build.dir}/var"/>
    <property name="codegen.timestamp.file" value="${build.src.dir}/.CODEGEN_DONE"/>
    <property name="war.dir" location="${build.dir}/war"/>
    <property name="wsdl.dir" location="${basedir}/wsdl"/>
    <!-- Determine cxf.home, either from the environment variable CXF_HOME
        - or using ../..
        -->
    <condition property="cxf.home" value="${env.CXF_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.CXF_HOME"/>
    </condition>
    <property name="cxf.home" location="../.."/>
    <property name="cxf.etc.dir" location="${cxf.home}/etc"/>
    <!-- JAX-WS 2.2 and JAXB 2.2 require the API jars to be endorsed -->
    <condition property="cxf.endorsed.dir" value="${cxf.home}/lib/endorsed">
        <available file="${cxf.home}/lib/endorsed" type="dir" property=""/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="cxf.endorsed.flag" value="-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${cxf.endorsed.dir}">
        <available file="${cxf.home}/lib/endorsed" type="dir" property=""/>
    </condition>
    <property name="cxf.endorsed.dir" location="${cxf.home}"/>
    <property name="cxf.endorsed.flag" value="-Dnone=none"/>
    <!-- Set the classpath for the CXF libraries -->
    <path id="cxf.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${basedir}"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <pathelement path="${srcbuild.classpath}"/>
        <pathelement location="${cxf.home}/lib/cxf-manifest.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${cxf.endorsed.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <!-- Sample macrodef to setup and run the CXF wsdl2java tool -->
    <macrodef name="wsdl2java">
        <attribute name="srcdestdir" default="${build.src.dir}"/>
        <attribute name="destdir" default="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <attribute name="file"/>
        <attribute name="servicename.arg" default=""/>
        <attribute name="bindingfile" default=""/>
        <attribute name="databinding" default=""/>
        <attribute name="dir" default="${wsdl.dir}"/>
        <attribute name="package" default="NOT_SPECIFIED"/>
        <sequential>
            <mkdir dir="@{destdir}"/>
            <mkdir dir="@{srcdestdir}"/>
            <condition property="package.arg.@{file}" value="-p @{package}">
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="@{package}" arg2="NOT_SPECIFIED"/>
                </not>
            </condition>
            <property name="package.arg.@{file}" value=""/>
            <condition property="binding.arg" value="-b &quot;@{bindingfile}&quot;">
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="@{bindingfile}" arg2=""/>
                </not>
            </condition>
            <property name="binding.arg" value=""/>
            <condition property="databinding.arg" value="-db &quot;@{databinding}&quot;">
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="@{databinding}" arg2=""/>
                </not>
            </condition>
            <property name="databinding.arg" value=""/>
            <java failonerror="true" classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="yes">
                <classpath>
                    <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
                </classpath>
                <jvmarg value="${cxf.endorsed.flag}"/>
                <sysproperty key="java.util.logging.config.file" value="${basedir}/logging.properties"/>
                <sysproperty key="exitOnFinish" value="true"/>
                <arg line="@{servicename.arg}"/>
                <arg line="${package.arg.@{file}}"/>
                <arg line="${databinding.arg}"/>
                <arg line="${binding.arg}"/>
                <arg value="-verbose"/>
                <arg value="-d"/>
                <arg value="@{srcdestdir}"/>
                <arg value="@{dir}/@{file}"/>
            </java>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
    <!-- Targets to run the sample client and server -->
    <target name="client" description="run demo client" depends="compile">
        <property name="param" value=""/>
        <cxfrun classname="com.orderProcessClient.service.Client"/>
    </target>
    <target name="server" description="run demo server" depends="compile">
        <cxfrun classname="com.orderProcess.service.OrderProcessImpl"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build"  depends="compile" description="build demo client and server"/>
    <!-- detect if the wsdl2java needs to be rerun -->
    <uptodate property="codegen.notrequired" value="true">
        <srcfiles dir="${wsdl.dir}" includes="**/*.wsdl"/>
        <srcfiles dir="${wsdl.dir}" includes="**/*.xsd"/>
        <mapper type="merge" to="${codegen.timestamp.file}"/>
    </uptodate>
    <target name="generate.code">
        <echo level="info" message="Generating code using wsdl2java..."/>
        <wsdl2java file="hello_world.wsdl"/>
    </target>
    <target name="maybe.generate.code" unless="codegen.notrequired">
        <antcall target="generate.code"/>
        <touch file="${codegen.timestamp.file}"/>
    </target>
    <!-- Compiles all the code.   Depends on the targets that would call wsdl2java -->
    <target name="compile" depends="maybe.generate.code">
        <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${build.src.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.classes.dir}" debug="true" fork="true" encoding="utf-8" includeantruntime="false">
            <compilerarg line="-J${cxf.endorsed.flag}"/>
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <src path="${build.src.dir}"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
                <path refid="spring.and.commons" />
                <path refid="cxf.extra.libs" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
            <fileset dir="${build.src.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean" description="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${build.src.dir}"/>
        <delete file="${codegen.timestamp.file}"/>
        <delete file="demo.log"/>
        <delete dir="${build.var.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <!-- Sample macrodef for running an application that would include the requirements that CXF needs
        It sets up the classpath and the endorsed dirs and add the logging properties and such -->

<path id="spring.and.commons">
    <fileset dir="/home/ramson/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="cxf.extra.libs">
    <fileset dir="/usr/local/apache-cxf-3.1.4">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

    <macrodef name="cxfrun">
        <attribute name="logging-properties-file" default="${cxf.etc.dir}/logging.properties"/>
        <attribute name="classname"/>
        <attribute name="param1" default=""/>
        <attribute name="param2" default=""/>
        <attribute name="param3" default=""/>
        <attribute name="param4" default=""/>
        <attribute name="param5" default=""/>
        <attribute name="jvmarg1" default="-D' '"/>
        <attribute name="jvmarg2" default="-D' '"/>
        <attribute name="jvmarg3" default="-D' '"/>
        <attribute name="jvmarg4" default="-D' '"/>
        <attribute name="jvmarg5" default="-D' '"/>
        <sequential>
            <java classname="@{classname}" fork="yes">
                <classpath>
                    <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
            <path refid="spring.and.commons" />
            <path refid="cxf.extra.libs" />
                </classpath>
                <arg value="@{param1}"/>
                <arg value="@{param2}"/>
                <arg value="@{param3}"/>
                <arg value="@{param4}"/>
                <arg value="@{param5}"/>
                <jvmarg value="-Dcxf.home=${cxf.home}"/>
                <jvmarg value="${cxf.endorsed.flag}"/>
                <jvmarg value="@{jvmarg1}"/>
                <jvmarg value="@{jvmarg2}"/>
                <jvmarg value="@{jvmarg3}"/>
                <jvmarg value="@{jvmarg4}"/>
                <jvmarg value="@{jvmarg5}"/>
                <sysproperty key="java.util.logging.config.file" value="@{logging-properties-file}"/>
            </java>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <macrodef name="wsdl2java">
        <attribute name="srcdestdir" default="${build.src.dir}"/>
        <attribute name="destdir" default="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <attribute name="file"/>
        <attribute name="servicename.arg" default=""/>
        <attribute name="bindingfile" default=""/>
        <attribute name="dir" default="${wsdl.dir}"/>
        <attribute name="package" default="NOT_SPECIFIED"/>
        <sequential>
            <mkdir dir="@{destdir}"/>
            <mkdir dir="@{srcdestdir}"/>
            <condition property="package.arg.@{file}" value="-p @{package}">
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="@{package}" arg2="NOT_SPECIFIED"/>
                </not>
            </condition>
            <property name="package.arg.@{file}" value=""/>
            <condition property="binding.arg" value='-b "@{bindingfile}"'>
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="@{bindingfile}" arg2=""/>
                </not>
            </condition>
            <property name="binding.arg" value=""/>
            <java failonerror="true" classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="yes">
                <classpath>
                    <path refid="cxf.classpath" />
                </classpath>
                <sysproperty key="java.util.logging.config.file" value="${cxf.etc.dir}/logging.properties"/>
                <sysproperty key="exitOnFinish" value="true"/>
                <arg line="@{servicename.arg}"/>
                <arg line="${package.arg.@{file}}"/>
                <arg line="${binding.arg}"/>
                <arg value="-verbose"/>
                <arg value="-d"/>
                <arg value="@{srcdestdir}"/>
                <arg value="@{dir}/@{file}"/>
            </java>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

        <property name="war-lib" value="${basedir}/libs" />
        <property name="config.dir" value="${basedir}/config" />
    <macrodef name="cxfwar">
        <attribute name="filename"/>
        <attribute name="wsdl" default=""/>
        <attribute name="dir" default="${war.dir}"/>
        <attribute name="classesdir" default="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <attribute name="webxml" default="${cxf.home}/etc/web.xml" />
        <sequential>
            <mkdir dir="@{dir}"/>
            <mkdir dir="${war-lib}"/>
            <mkdir dir="${config.dir}"/>
            <antcall target="copy-war-libs"/>

            <available property="has.config" file="${basedir}/webapp/WEB-INF" type="dir" />
            <antcall target="copy-config-files" />

            <delete file="@{dir}/@{filename}" />
            <war destfile="@{dir}/@{filename}" webxml="@{webxml}">
                <classes dir="@{classesdir}"/>
                <webinf dir="${wsdl.dir}">
                    <include name="cxf-servlet.xml"/>
                </webinf>
                <webinf dir="${wsdl.dir}/..">
                    <include name="wsdl/@{wsdl}"/>
                </webinf>
                <webinf dir="${config.dir}">
                        <include name="*.*" />
                </webinf> 
                <lib dir="${war-lib}">
                                <include name="*.jar"/>
                            </lib>
            </war>

            <delete dir="${war-lib}" />
            <delete dir="${config.dir}" />
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="copy-war-libs" unless="without.libs">
        <copy todir="${war-lib}">
            <fileset dir="${cxf.home}/lib">
               <exclude name="servlet-api-*.jar" />
                   <exclude name="geronimo-servlet_*.jar" />
                   <exclude name="jetty-*.jar"/>
                   <exclude name="WHICH_JARS" />
            </fileset>
        </copy> 
    </target>

    <target name="copy-config-files" if="has.config">
            <copy todir="${config.dir}" >
                <fileset dir="${basedir}/webapp/WEB-INF">
                    <include name="*.xml" />
                    <exclude name="web.xml" />
                </fileset>
            </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" description="deploy the application into the container">
        <antcall target="war"/>
        <antcall target="deploy-tomcat"/>
    </target>
    <target name="undeploy" depends="undeploy-tomcat" description="undeploy the application from the container"/>

    <target name="deploy-tomcat">
        <antcall target="validate-tomcat"/>
        <copy file="${war.dir}/${cxf.war.file.name}.war"
              todir="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/webapps"/>
    </target>

    <target name="undeploy-tomcat">
        <antcall target="validate-tomcat"/>
        <delete file="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/${cxf.war.file.name}.war"/>
        <delete dir="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/${cxf.war.file.name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="validate-tomcat">
        <fail unless="env.CATALINA_HOME" message="You should set the CATALINA_HOME, if you want to deploy into tomcat"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

now, this is my pain:
When I run the client

```
ant client
```

I get this error:

```
Buildfile: /home/ramson/NetBeansProjects/OrderProcessingSystem/masterbuild/build.xml
Trying to override old definition of task wsdl2java

maybe.generate.code:

compile:

build:

client:
     [java] Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
     [java]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.processOrder(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at com.orderProcessClient.service.Client.main(Client.java:32)
     [java] Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '404: Not Found' when communicating with http://127.0.0.1:8080/OrderProcess
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1526)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1486)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1305)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:623)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:541)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
     [java]     ... 2 more
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Initialy I though maybe there would be a difference if I include the war name in the url, but there is none.

```
address="http://127.0.0.1:8080/OrderProcess"
```

and

```
address="http://127.0.0.1:8080/OrderProcessingSystem/OrderProcess"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your "web.xml", you defined your `CXFServlet` on following URL pattern: "/services/*". Your endpoint is published on "/OrderProcess".

As a result your service address in your client would need to be: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/OrderProcess".

Depending on how you deploy, you might need to include the WAR name as you mentioned. In that case the address becomes: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/OrderProcessingSystem/services/OrderProcess".

Comment: Hello. Thanks. Still the same. I have changed /services/* to just /*. still the same error.

Comment: What happens if you open following URL via a browser: http://127.0.0.1:8080/OrderProcessingSystem/services

Comment: I get a 404 error. Am thinking maybe its the deployment that has errors. But I have googled everywhere and seems its the same method.

Comment: I've seen where the error is but am not able to solve it. In catalina.out, my app is not deploying properly because of

Comment: nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Can you try to remove these three imports, I think Spring automatically loads these configurations as of CXF 2.4.

Comment: I get this error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLServiceFactory
I have downloaded cxf-rt-wsdl and included it in the lib of my project. Still the same

Comment: I have seen where the conflict was, in my build file, I also included Spring lib path, after removing it everything is ok. I dint realize CXF comes with its own Spring libraries. ooohhh the headache